# I am not able to add elements to Ko.ObservableArray

Tags: knockout.js

in the following code I am trying to add an object int the self.data which is an ObservableArray but after iteration self.data has 0 elements in it. Can you guys please help me what I am missing?

Thanks for your effort in advance

```
var self = this;
        self.data = ko.observableArray();
        // self.data = [{ icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-11/512/add-item-icon.png', item_name: '11:24 am', item_desc: '24/01', item_rate: 'Edited Online Form and got "Digital Signature" by Samantha Brown' },
        // { icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-11/512/add-item-icon.png', item_name: '11:24 am', item_desc: '24/01', item_rate: 'Edited Online Form and got "Digital Signature" by Samantha Brown' },
        // { icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-11/512/add-item-icon.png', item_name: '11:24 am', item_desc: '24/01', item_rate: 'Edited Online Form and got "Digital Signature" by Samantha Brown' },
        // { icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-11/512/add-item-icon.png', item_name: '11:24 am', item_desc: '24/01', item_rate: 'Edited Online Form and got "Digital Signature" by Samantha Brown' },
        // { icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-11/512/add-item-icon.png', item_name: '11:24 am', item_desc: '24/01', item_rate: 'Edited Online Form and got "Digital Signature" by Samantha Brown' }
        // ];


        function DashboardViewModel() {
            this.nowrap = ko.observable(false);

            $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:3000/items/").
                then(function (items) {
                    console.log(">> " + items[0].item_desc);
                    $.each(items, function () {
                        var item = {
                            icon: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-11/512/add-item-icon.png',
                            item_name: this.item_name,
                            item_desc: this.item_desc,
                            item_rate: this.item_rate
                        };
                        self.data.push(item);
                        console.log(self.data.length);
                    });
                });
            self.dataSource = new oj.ArrayTableDataSource(self.data, { idAttribute: "item_name" });
        }
```

And following is the HTML code,

```
  <div class="oj-flex oj-flex-items-pad">
    <div class="oj-sm-4 oj-md-6 oj-lg-12 oj-flex-item fontStyle" style="text-align: start;">
      <ul id="listview" aria-label="list with context menu" contextmenu="myMenu" data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojListView', data: dataSource, item: {template: 'server_template'}, selectionMode: 'single'}">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why add that single property? Can't you put that in the template HTML? Then you don't have to iterate your resultset.

Comment: Bro this is the first time I am using javascript. so It will be great if you can explain to me what do you mean. :) I am sorry for not able to understand.
I have also added the HTML code in the snippet

Comment: I've added an answer. But I suggest you run through a couple of Javascript, AJAX and then Knockout tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log(self.data().length);
```

With the added parentheses.

`ko.observableArray` does not have a `length` property so you have to unwrap the inner array first.

Also `self.data()` instead of `self.data` on the last row. In case that `oj.ArrayTableDataSource` expects a standard array rather than a `ko.observableArray`.

Comment: Oh my goodness. it worked thanks a lot. You are a gem. I have been banging my head for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel:

```
var self = this;
self.data = ko.observableArray();

$.get("url").done(function(result) {
   self.data(result);
});
return self;
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: data">
   <div>
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/pretty-office-11/512/add-item-icon.png" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div data-bind="text: item_name"></div>
</div>
```